# Strange vertical space on text

Tags: margin, font-face, css

I'm having a strange issue with some @font-face text where there is some strange padding (or at least vertical space) included with the text. It is causing problems because I want to text to be positioned a certain way but can't have it overlapping other things. Here is a picture of what is occurring:

[image]

As you can see when the text is selected, the text overlaps some of the navigation bar above it. I have tried adjusting the line height and padding, margins, anything I can think of. Here is the relevant CSS, does anybody have a suggestion as to how I can get the height of the line to be around the height of the actual text.

```
  *{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  h1#logo { font: 350px/.95 'Bebas Neue'; color: #DDD; text-align: center; margin: 1px 0; }
```

**EDIT**: Here is a live example of the problem: http://codezroz.com/stuff/hello.html

Comment: not sure what the actual problem is, but keep in mind that you can always have negative margin/padding as a quick solution. I always use `top: -10px` to make things flush with the top of my screen. kind of hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never seen the `/.95` syntax before, but after a few tests now i belive it works like:
`line-height = 0.95 * font-size = 332.5`
so i think that's your problem, the font is taller than the line
adding `overflow: hidden;` on the H1 should be enough

Comment: That syntax is the correct syntax for the `font` shorthand property. The usage is `font-size/line-height`. Numbers without units are treated as percentages so you're conclusion is correct, though your answer is now essentially the same as mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, applying `overflow: hidden` to `h1#logo` stopped the selection highlight from bleeding into areas that were outside the element.

Also remember that you can use the [`:selection`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-selection) pseudo-element to change the color of the selected text.